# Does "Invalidate Caches" in Intelij IDEA clear any build related caches?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am running my Java web application through `Intellij IDEA`. There was a certain bug in my app which occurs randomly.

One of my colleagues told me that this bug could have occurred due to some error in `IDEA` and told me to do a **Invalidate Caches** in `IDEA` and retry. After doing so, the bug hasn't occurred so far.

But, when I searched about what **Invalidate Caches** does, what I basically found was it clears some indexes it has built on code when **Invalidate Caches** is performed.

So, does `IDEA` clean any build related caches which could have led to resolving my issue?

Comment: Does the bug occur in run-time, compile time or is it maybe a markup related thing?

Comment: Are you running the app from within intellij?

Comment: @AleksandarStojadinovic, bug occurs at runtime, in my vaadin application

Comment: @JuanMendes I am using `tomcat` run configuration in IDEA

Comment: If you restart the app, it works fine? I wouldn't worry about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are building and deploying via IntelliJ, then - yes, invalidate caches will delete build-related information, and this is likely what resolved your problem.

On the other hand if you are building and deploying externally (e.g. build via maven, deploy via a script) then that build related information is not related to the internal intellij caches.